# Trying to generate numbers with eventListener

Tags: javascript

I want generate random lottery numbers, ranging from 1-59 with 7 numbers showing. They have to generate on the click of a submit button. Im struggling to get it to write to the console log saying random is not defined.

```
let lottoNum = [];
while (lottoNum.length < 7) {
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 59) + 1;
  if (lottoNum.indexOf(random) === -1) lottoNum.push(random);
}

let btn = document.getElementById("Button");
button.addEventListener("click", function getNumbers() {
  return random;
});
```

> random is not defined

Comment: You're declaring `random` using `let` inside a `while` loop. Therefore it will not be in scope outside the loop. Fixed code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/1e072yjq/

Comment: Don't you want to return `lottoNum`?

Comment: yes needs to return lottoNumb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You was close, you should research into scopes however. Try the following:

```
generateNumbers = () => {
  let lottoNum = [];
  while (lottoNum.length < 7) {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 59) + 1;
    if (lottoNum.indexOf(random) === -1) lottoNum.push(random);
  }
  return lottoNum;
}

let btn = document.getElementById("Button");
btn.addEventListener("click", function getNumbers() {
  const nums =  generateNumbers();
  console.log(nums);
});
```

I've put your main code into a function and returned it from said function. From there i've called the function in your click listener and logged them. You can do anything you'd like where i've done `console.log` however.

The reason you had your "random is not defined" is because you do `let random` inside your `while` loop. That means anything that isn't inside of the `{}` of your while loop cannot read random. hence the function and return :)